# Use a custom label in a custom URL formula

Tags: formula, custom-button, customlabel

I am working on an assignment where a custom URL needs to be provided on the Contact to open a training portal website when clicked. The DEMO and PROD salesforce instances need to open different training portal sites. So, I have created a custom label which will have different values for the base URLs for DEMO and PROD. The custom link formula on the Contact is below.

```
{!$Label.Advisor_Training_Portal_URL}/Details/{!Contact.AgentId__c}
```

However, this is not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

You're using Visualforce merge format, which doesn't work in formula fields, and also not including any concatenation operator.

Your formula field should look like this:

```
$Label.Advisor_Training_Portal_URL & "/Details/" & AgentId__c
```

You could also us the `HYPERLINK()` function if you want to specify the link text or target:

```
HYPERLINK($Label.Advisor_Training_Portal_URL & "/Details/" & AgentId__c, FirstName & "'s Training Portal", "_blank")
```